# error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 3.)

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I am using Jenkins automation build for iOS.

Previously I have been using xcode 8.1 with no error showing. But i have updated the xcode to 8.3 and I'm facing errors now. I have the scripts as below:

OLD SCRIPT

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath Sample.xcarchive -exportPath Sample -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile 'Sampledemo'

xcodebuild: error: invalid option '-exportFormat'
```

NEW SCRIPT

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist -archivePath Sample.xcarchive -exportPath Sample  PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="Sampledemo"

error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 3.)

Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={IDEDistributionErrorSigningIdentityToItemToUnderlyingErrorKey={
```

but I'm facing this issue now. How can I solve the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75038

> Hi!
>
> I think I've got it figured out...
>
> instead of:
>
> ```
> -exportProvisioningProfile "MyProvisioningProfile"
> ```
>
> use:
>
> ```
> PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="MyProvisioningProfile"
> ```
>
> We've got unity building the project every time and it doesn't fill in
>   the PROVISIONING_PROFILE or PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER. And it
>   looks like it will figure out the alphabet soup that belongs to
>   PROVISIONING_PROFILE by looking it up itself provided you have
>   downloaded it already.